# Iterating through records with SQL INSERT activated stops after first set of INSERTS, but using PRINT to test goes through EVERY record (as desired)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, logic

Python 3.10.2 with sqlite3 on Windows 10. Relatively new to Python, but I was quite experienced with Perl around 1997-2005.

Banged my head against this for three days. Attacked from lots of angles. No success. I'm asking for guidance, because I don't see myself progressing on my own at this point without help flipping on the light-switch.

My overall application utilizes `PRAW` to scrape a subreddit and put the Submissions into a table. Then, we go through that reddit table one row at a time, scanning the `selftext` column for any URLs. Disregard some. Clean up others. Insert the ones we want into another table. At a later point, I'll then go through that table, downloading each URL.

My problem is that if I run the below code, with the `INSERT` commented out, my `print(dl_lnk[0])` line prints out the results of all (currently) 1,400 rows from the reddit table. But if I activate the `INSERT` line, it only seems to process the first row in the table. I can assume this to be the case, because the print line only shows a few lines and they are all regarding the same user and the same/similar URL.

I don't understand why this is. I don't think it's because of an error in SQL (though there seems to be fewer options for accessing SQL exceptions in-code than I used to have in Perl, inherently).  But I also don't see anything about my flow logic that would make it process just one row when an SQL INSERT happens but processes through all of them when it's commented out.

```
def scanForDownloadLinks(db):
    cursorObj = db.cursor()
    # Get all records from 'reddit' submission table.
    for reddit_row in cursorObj.execute('''SELECT name, author, subreddit, permalink, title, selftext FROM reddit ORDER BY CREATED_UTC ASC'''):
        # Build URL-matching regex
        link_regex = re.compile('((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)', re.DOTALL)
        # Find all URLs in this reddit submission's selftext column.
        dl_links = re.findall(link_regex, reddit_row[5])
        # Go through each link, disregard links we don't want, clean up links we do, then insert them into the dl_link table
        for dl_lnk in dl_links:
            print(dl_lnk[0])
            cursorObj.execute('''INSERT INTO dl_ledger (name, title, dl_link) VALUES(?,?,?)''', (reddit_row[0], str(reddit_row[4]), dl_lnk[0]))
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Try using a separate cursor for the inserts?

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb, that did turn out to be the issue. I suppose I might have figured that out given enough time, but I was nowhere close to traveling down that path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different cursors for the `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries. When you use the same cursor, the `INSERT` resets the cursor so you can't fetch the remaining rows.

Or you could use `cursorObj.fetchall()` to get all the results of the `SELECT` query as a list and loop through that, rather than looping through the cursor itself. But if there are lots of rows, this will use lots of memory, while looping through the cursor is incremental. But 1400 rows may not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried using `fetchall()` as a solution before, but received an error that `fetchall() takes no arguments`, but `1 was supplied` (but I don't supply an argument..). I'm not sure what I'm overlooking there.
  
Of course, using a separate cursor makes complete sense now that you pointed it out and it does work (but I wasn't remotely on the path to figuring that out  on my  own). T hank you very much!

Comment: How did you use `fetchAll()`? It should be `cursorObj.execute('query)` followed by `for row in cursorObj.fetchall():`

Comment: Nope,  I was using that improperly by literally just replacing `.execute` with `.fetchAll()`, which means I apparently _was_  technically feeding it an argument. Thanks for your response today, which  got me  past a hurdle and into the flow again!